# systemd automatism to update enabled unit symlink when updating units

Tags: linux, centos7, systemd, service

Is there a way in systemd to update existing target want symlinks when updating a unit by a newer version higher in the unit load paths hierarchy?

On CentOS `3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64` with systemd @ `219-78` I have had a service unit enabled for multi user as target using the default unit.

I.e., the symlink

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/foo.service
```

pointed to the package's original unit

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/foo.service
```

Later on, I deployed a modified version of the unit to

```
/etc/systemd/system/foo.service
```

After running `systemd daemon-reload`, systemd knew in principle about the updated unit. However, after rebooting the node, the original service unit was started again by `systemd` as the symlink did not get updated.

I had do disable/enable the unit explicitly, i.e., removing and setting the symlink again to point it to the updated unit's location.

Is there a way to update target symlinks automatically similarly to `daemon-reload`, when a unit get's updated after a unit version is placed higher up in sytemd's path hierarchy?

Comment: As a general rule you should be using overrides rather than trying to replace the entire unit. This would not have occurred if you had done so.

Comment: @MichaelHampton unfortunately, I do not consider systemctl's edit/overwrite not really applicable for machines under control of a configuration management like puppet, ansible etc.

Comment: Eh? That is exactly what they are good for!